# most optimal way to implement special function registers in Systemverilog

Tags: structure, system-verilog

I am implementing my Special Function Registers using structures, I can choose between packed structures and unpacked structures, the advantage of the packed structures is that they allow me to be able to treat my structure as a vector, but the downside is that from a synthesis point of view, unpacked structures are better, because "synthesis compilers might be able to optimize unpacked structures better than packed structures".

I am wondering if it would make sense to use unpacked structures at all, even for the above synthesis considerations.

Thanks.

*Quote from the book "RTL modeling with SystemVerilog", Stuart Sutherland.*

Comment: ["Most optimal"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114273) is logically wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the packed or unpacked declaration that matters, it the operations you wind up performing on the structures. If you write the exact same code using *packed* or *unpacked*, it won't matter to synthesis. But like you say, if you want to perform bitwise operations like xor on the entire struct, than it becomes more difficult using an unpacked struct.